# Wrong json is generating

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to generate an array having multiple jsons in which different keys and values exist but, when I look in to generated array, I found same keys in each json.

Please look at the code below:

```
var jsonObjStyle = [];
var uniqueclass = '';

$("*", newObj).each(function (e) {
    if($(this).attr('style')){
        uniqueclass = 'class'+new Date().getTime();
        jsonObjStyle.push({
                uniqueclass:$(this).attr('style')
        });
    }
});
```

Generated array:

```
[{"uniqueclass":"left: 457.55px; top: 331px;"},{"uniqueclass":"height: auto; display: block;"},{"uniqueclass":"text-align: center;"},{"uniqueclass":"z-index: 1001;"}]
```

In every json, I found same key, uniqueclass

Can anybody please tell me where I am wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript's object literal syntax, object property names ("keys") are literal. To use variable names, do something like:

```
var entry = {};
entry[uniqueclass] = $(this).attr('style');
jsonObjStyle.push(entry);
```

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge sharing! It helps me a bit. Please look at updated post which lets you know what actual happening after applying your code.

Comment: Well, the time is probably always the same. Use a different random number generator than the current time. And please don't edit amendments to the question into the answer.

Comment: sorry! by mistake i have edited amendments to the question into the answer. next time i will try not to do that.